# Inter- and Intra- Listbox Loop Error

Tags: excel, loops, listbox, runtime-error, vba

```
Dim InputCol, InputIndex, i As Long
Dim lb As ListBox
InputCol = 1

For i = 1 To 7
    Set lb = Me.Controls("ListBox" & i)
        For InputIndex = 0 To lb.ListCount - 1
            If lb.Selected(InputIndex) Then
                Sheets("Sheets2").Cells(1, InputCol) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Input" & i).Cells(InputIndex)
                InputCol = InputCol + 1
            End If
        Next
Next i
```

I'm trying to use the above code to loop through multiple listboxes in a userform. The listboxes derive data from named ranges on Sheet1 and then pass headings to Sheet2. The Sheet1 ranges align with the listboxes by number. Unfortunately, I'm receiving a Run-time error '13': Type mismatch referencing the line:

```
Set lb = Me.Controls("ListBox" & i)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huge thanks to Shai Rado for showing me the right direction. The following code worked to loop through all listboxes on the userform and pass each selected item to a header row on Sheet2:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim InputCol As Long, InputIndex As Long, i As Long
Dim lb As Control
InputCol = 1

With lb
    For i = 1 To 7
        Set lb = Me.Controls("ListBox" & i)
            For InputIndex = 0 To lb.ListCount - 1
                If lb.Selected(InputIndex) Then
                    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, InputCol) = _ 
                    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Input" & i).Cells(InputIndex + 1)
                    InputCol = InputCol + 1
                End If
            Next
    Next i
End With
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below to loop through all `Control` in a `UserForm`, and check if the current control is a `ListBox`.

**Note**: `Dim InputCol, InputIndex, i As Long` , means only `i` is defined as `Long`, while `InputCol` and `InputIndex` are defined `As Variant`.

**Code**

```
Dim InputCol As Long, InputIndex As Long, i As Long
Dim lb As Control
InputCol = 1

' loop through all control in UserForm
For Each lb In Me.Controls
    ' check if current Control is a LitBox
    If TypeName(lb) = "ListBox" Then
        With lb
            ' rest of your code goes here

        End With          
    End If
Next lb
```

Comment: I'm still new to VBA so apologies in advance. Which section of the original code can be placed after "With lb"? I tried putting everything from "For i = 1 To 7" to "Next i" within your code but that led to the same cell being copied to Sheet2 7 times. I also tried removing the i and creating an i = i +1 just before the "Next lb" but then I started receiving defined range errors. For some reason, debug highlighted the copying Sheet to Sheet line and showed i = 19 (which makes sense, there is no "Input19" named range, only Input1 through Input7). Appreciate any further clarification!